# How to convey your full length paper in conference through slides?

Tags: presentation

I am a PhD student works in computer algebra(Theoretical computer science). I have published one research paper recently, I am currently making slides for the paper. It is my first time and believe me I am struggling a lot. I have spent 4 days but till now not able to convey the idea that I want to deliver to the audience. I have given 30 mins for the presentation. My algorithm is based on 4-5 other algorithm with few lemma and some modification to previous algorithms. I am confused how to make slides such that I can convey my work efficiently.

Should I focus more on modified previous results or on new lemma. Should I first explain them notations and definition or directly go to the results.

**Questiom :** How to convey your full length paper in conference through slides?

Edit : Audience is Professor and Ph.D students of computer science and mathematics.

Comment: Think about how you would [dance your content](https://www.sciencemag.org/projects/dance-your-phd).

Comment: Important information is missing: Who is your audience? How much do they already know about your topic?

Comment: some of them may be first time listening about algebra

Comment: I can read mathematics, if motivated and given time with nobody talking to me. I can also recognize some common formulae, and understand small variations. Notation you have to introduce would do me no good at all. Ideas and intuition might motivate me to study your paper.

Answer (score 3):

In a short face to face presentation, remember that insight is much more important and valuable than detail. People aren't going to remember the detail, and can get it from the paper if they need it, but they *will* remember if you can show them why your main result is true from a chain of insights.

Answer (score 0):

Set out as plan for your slides and then discuss with your advisor / supervisor.

They can then suggest changes as necessary and you can then do the next level of detail which can then be checked.

This will be an iterative process, much like your calculations. At the end you should have a good presentation - but it will never be perfect: there will always be one question that needs something else...